# Airflow pyodbc can use dsn fine in test, fails when running dag via UI

Tags: docker, airflow, pyodbc, impala

I'm using pyodbc (in an airflow task python callable) to connect to a database via airflow (running in docker). DSN gets connection args from an odbc.ini file within the docker container.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN=DSN_NAME, autocommit=True)
...some code to execute SQL statement
conn.close()
```

When I run it via CLI test it works fine

```
airflow tasks test dag_name task_name 2022-1-3
```

However, when I run it via the Airflow UI (in localhost) it seems the data source can't be found:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Why would the DSN reference work fine in testing but not via the localhost UI instance?

Comment: Could this be something to do with the user permissions inside the container? Could the UI be running the Dag from a different user then the CLI test? Is it possible to identify and bump up permissions for this user?

Comment: Anyone any ideas?